# How do i parse a string with a JSON array to variables so i can put them in html tables?

Tags: java, html, json, rest, servlets

I have a WebServlet called Items and in the doGet method i send a JSON array and i receive that array and put it into a string but now i can't put it back into JSON objets so i can retrive the values to put in an html page.

```
 HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://localhost:8080/items/?get=item").openConnection();
 con.setRequestMethod("GET");
 con.setDoInput(true);
 con.connect();

 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
 String stringJson = reader.readLine();
 JsonArray array = Json.createParser(stringJson);
```

What i want now is to put the objets in the array so i can get the values.
I have tried to us JsonParser but i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need to pass stringJson to Json. Give a try by using [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) library:

```
try {
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringJson);
}catch (JSONException err){
     logger.error("Error", err.toString());
}
```